# .ajax call not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome

I am having a ajax call which parses the xml file. I have set the async to false, but still it is not working. I had the alert before and after the ajax call and it seems to be working in succession. can any one please let me know where I am going wrong. Here is the code segment that what I am doing

```
var i = 0;

var xmlLength = 0;
var arr = new Array();

alert("1");
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "sample.xml",
  async: false,
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function (xml) {
    $(xml).find('CD').each(function () {
      alert("2");
      i = i + 1;
      xmlLength += 1;

      var title;
      var getTo;
      var artist;
      var getToNode;
      var $allToElements = 'TO';

      var country = $(this).find('COUNTRY').text();
      getTo = $(this).find('TO'); //.text();

      if (getTo.length > 1) {
        var $divId = "window" + i;
        $('<div class="window" id="window' + i + '" />')
          .append('<div class="topright" id="topright' + i + '"/>')
          .append('<div class="topleft" id="topleft' + i + '"/>')
          .append('<div class="bottomright" id="bottomright' + i + '"/>')
          .append('<div class="bottomleft" id="bottomleft' + i + '"/>')
          .appendTo('div#demo1');
        var countr = $(this).find('COUNTRY').text();
        $('div#topright' + i).append(countr);
        $('div#topleft' + i).append('NW');
        $('div#bottomleft' + i).append('SW');
        $('div#bottomright' + i).append('SE');
        var j = 0;
        $(this).find('TO').each(function () {
          var $name = $(this).text();
          j += 1;
          $('div#window' + i).append($('<p id="to' + i + '">').text($name));
        });
      } else {
        var $divId = "window" + i;

        $('<div class="window" id="window' + i + '" />')
          .append('<div class="topright" id="topright' + i + '"/>')
          .append('<div class="topleft" id="topleft' + i + '"/>')
          .append('<div class="bottomright" id="bottomright' + i + '"/>')
          .append('<div class="bottomleft" id="bottomleft' + i + '"/>')

          .append($('<p id="to' + i + '">').text(getTo.text()))
          .appendTo('div#demo1');
        var countr = $(this).find('COUNTRY').text();

        $('div#topright' + i).append(countr);
        $('div#topleft' + i).append('NW');
        $('div#bottomleft' + i).append('SW');
        $('div#bottomright' + i).append('SE');
      }

      arr[i] = getTo;
    }); //end of find
  }
}); //end of ajax function

var j;
alert("3");
```

Thanks!

Comment: What error did the console give you?

Comment: are you working with webserver (http://) or just opening with file:// . for ajax, you need run on webserver like apache. it can't work on direct open file://

Comment: What succession of alerts do you get when this runs?

Comment: @saturngod:I am using apache web server and running on localhost

Comment: @arxanas: i have declared i as var and set to 0

Comment: @unix_user That is relevant code. Please include any other declarations (like `xmlLength`).

Comment: @SperanskyDanil: alerts 1 & 3 work. alert("2") does not work

Comment: Logically, either the Ajax call or the Xml parse must be failing.  I'd first check Firebug (network section) to see whether the XML file loaded.

Comment: Note: `async:false` is deprecated as of 1.8: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @dbaseman: The xml file is in the same folder where the .js file is.

Comment: @Chris:Then what should be done.

Comment: @saturngod: The fault was, i was doing file:// and not localhost/ thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that Google Chrome does not work with local files by XmlHttpRequest (which is used for ajax and `jQuery.ajax` function). So you cannot load file which path looks like `file://...`.

Comment: @seperansky: there is no xmlHttpRequest in the application

Comment: @arxanas: So this means i cant run the application in google chrome browser?

Comment: @unix_user It depends: are the files you're trying to access local? Either way, the answer is probably that you can if you try hard enough.

Comment: @arxanas: Yes the files are local. The xml file is in the same directory where my .js file

Comment: @SperanskyDanil: There I am wrong. I did not checked it correctly. It was file:// and not localhost. Thanks a lot for pointing this.

Comment: @SperanskyDanil: Can you help me with some CSS problem. It is making me nuts big time and i dnt know how to figure it out.

Comment: Response to 1st Answer: it is possible to setup Chrome to allow file AJAX access work on your computer. Add parameter '--allow-file-access-from-files' to chrome command line.

Comment: Or you can setup a web server on your local machine, create a site and point to the folder with your files.